# PDO Does Not Show Alert to Wrong Host

Tags: php, pdo

I recently missed the PDO syntax and it took me a few hours to figure out what the error was. No error has been reported on the page. It was not for codamental catch.

How can I show error in these cases?

I used

```
new PDO ("mysql:localhost; dbname=crud", "root", "");
```

When the correct one was

```
new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=crud", "root", "");
```

Yes I have

```
ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
```

activated and the condition

```
try {} catch (PDOException $ e) {}
```

and even then no error is displayed.

Comment: Ensure you have set `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` otherwise a blank page will be displayed.The  [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) constructor should throw an exception upon failure to connect to the specified database. In which case you would need to use a [`try/catch`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.catch) block to handle the error as desired

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: It is not duplicate. Even with these settings no error is displayed

Comment: You have to ensure `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` are both above the `new \PDO()` line for them to be applied if they are disabled in your ini file. As per https://3v4l.org/napvC You should actually see a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]` exception immediately since `new PDO` has to be called before using `$pdo->setAttribute()`. Otherwise with either disabled, you will see no errors https://3v4l.org/AIUns and https://3v4l.org/QRELl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO has default mode silent (`PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`). That means it won't throw exception on bad connection. 
So you need to set its attribute mode to throw exception:

```
try {

    $dbh = new PDO ("mysql:localhost; dbname=crud", "root", "");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo 'Bad Connection. Error: ' . $e->getMessage();

}
```

more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: `PDO::__construct` does throw an exception by default https://3v4l.org/napvC, as such `::setAttribute` is never called. The `::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE)` applies for all other method calls from the PDO instanced object, such as `->prepare()`.